# Can R produce frequency tables for one variable?

Tags: r

**Disclaimer:** I am new to Stackoverflow and R:

I have a data set call "house" with multiple columns. I am trying to obtain different frequency tables for each columns, without having them interact with each other. For this example: I am trying to obtain the overall count of houses that have pools and those that don't have pools. Sort of like a proc freq in SAS, where you do:

```
proc freq data = house; 

   tables pool backyard park_near / missing list; 

run;
```

But don't have any of the variables interacting with each other.

I use the following code in R:

```
freq_2<- freqlist(table(house[("Pool")], useNA = "ifany"))

print.noquote(head(as.data.frame(freq_2), n=100L))
```

However, I get:

```
    Var1     Freq cumFreq freqPercent cumPercent

1     N        64   64      88.88889     88.88889 

2     Y         8   72      11.11111    100.00000
```

Is there anyway I can get "Pool" instead of "Var1"? Also is there an easier way of doing this in R?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Base R with `arsenal::freqlist()`

The code from the question uses `arsenal::freqlist()` to replicate the output from SAS PROC FREQ. Unfortunately, when printing `freqlist()` results as a data frame, the first column always renders as `Var1`, regardless of the actual variable whose frequencies are being printed.

A very simple fix is to rename the column before printing via the `colnames()` function. We can combine this with `lapply()` to create frequency tables for multiple columns from a data frame.

Here is an example that combines `lapply()` with `colnames()` to rename the `Var1` column for multiple frequency tables with data from the `mtcars` data set since the OP does not include a reproducible example.

```
library(arsenal)
lapply(c("cyl","am","carb"),function(x,y){
     freqs <- freqlist(table(y[x],useNA = "ifany"))
     freq_df <- as.data.frame(freqs)
     colnames(freq_df)[1] <- x
     freq_df
},mtcars)
```

...and the output:

```
[[1]]
  cyl Freq cumFreq freqPercent cumPercent
1   4   11      11      34.375     34.375
2   6    7      18      21.875     56.250
3   8   14      32      43.750    100.000

[[2]]
  am Freq cumFreq freqPercent cumPercent
1  0   19      19      59.375     59.375
2  1   13      32      40.625    100.000

[[3]]
  carb Freq cumFreq freqPercent cumPercent
1    1    7       7      21.875     21.875
2    2   10      17      31.250     53.125
3    3    3      20       9.375     62.500
4    4   10      30      31.250     93.750
5    6    1      31       3.125     96.875
6    8    1      32       3.125    100.000
```

### A tidyverse solution

However, we can generate output similar in nature to `freqlist()` with a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr`. First, we select the columns that we want to tabulate, then we convert to narrow format tidy data. Next, we `summarise()` counts for each value of each variable, and calculate cumulative frequencies and percentages.

```
mtcars %>% mutate(model = rownames(.)) %>% 
     group_by(model) %>% select(model,cyl,carb,am) %>% 
     pivot_longer(.,-model,names_to = "variable",values_to = "value") %>% 
     mutate(count = 1) %>% group_by(variable,value) %>%
     summarise(freq = sum(count)) %>% group_by(variable) %>%
     mutate(cumFreq = cumsum(freq),
               pct = freq / sum(freq) * 100,
            cumPct = cumsum(pct)) -> freqData
```

We print the rows for each variable with `filter()`.

```
> freqData %>% filter(variable == "am")
# A tibble: 2 x 6
# Groups:   variable [1]
  variable value  freq cumFreq   pct cumPct
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 am           0    19      19  59.4   59.4
2 am           1    13      32  40.6  100  
> freqData %>% filter(variable == "cyl")
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Groups:   variable [1]
  variable value  freq cumFreq   pct cumPct
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 cyl          4    11      11  34.4   34.4
2 cyl          6     7      18  21.9   56.2
3 cyl          8    14      32  43.8  100  
> freqData %>% filter(variable == "carb")
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   variable [1]
  variable value  freq cumFreq   pct cumPct
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 carb         1     7       7 21.9    21.9
2 carb         2    10      17 31.2    53.1
3 carb         3     3      20  9.38   62.5
4 carb         4    10      30 31.2    93.8
5 carb         6     1      31  3.12   96.9
6 carb         8     1      32  3.12  100  
>
```

With a minor adjustment to the code that prints the data, we can drop the `variable` column and rename the `value` column with the original variable name. As we did with the `arsenal` solution, we can automate this with a list of categorical variables by using `lapply()`.

```
lapply(c("am","cyl","carb"),
                    function(x){
                       colnames(freqData)[2] <- x
                       y <- freqData[freqData$variable == x,][,-1]
                       rownames(y) <- NULL
                       y
                    })
```

...and the output:

```
[[1]]
  am freq cumFreq    pct  cumPct
1  0   19      19 59.375  59.375
2  1   13      32 40.625 100.000

[[2]]
  cyl freq cumFreq    pct  cumPct
1   4   11      11 34.375  34.375
2   6    7      18 21.875  56.250
3   8   14      32 43.750 100.000

[[3]]
  carb freq cumFreq    pct  cumPct
1    1    7       7 21.875  21.875
2    2   10      17 31.250  53.125
3    3    3      20  9.375  62.500
4    4   10      30 31.250  93.750
5    6    1      31  3.125  96.875
6    8    1      32  3.125 100.000
```

Finally, we can improve the look of the output by introducing `knitr::kable()`.

```
library(knitr)
atable <- freqData %>% filter(variable == "am") %>% rename(.,am = value) %>% select(-variable)
kable(atable)

| am| freq| cumFreq|    pct|  cumPct|
|--:|----:|-------:|------:|-------:|
|  0|   19|      19| 59.375|  59.375|
|  1|   13|      32| 40.625| 100.000|
```

When rendered in a web browser (or R Markdown document), the result looks like this.

[image]

For reference, the SAS equivalent looks like this:

```
filename cars "/folders/myfolders/data/mtcars.csv";

data mtcars;
   infile cars dlm="," firstobs = 2;
   input car $ mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb;
   run;

proc freq data = mtcars; 
   tables cyl  am carb / missing list; 
   run;
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful! I was about to use the function you introduce to get the numbers I needed. In the function you created, by having "cyl" you are introducing the X variable of the function before you introduce the function? and then mtcars is the Y variable?" I just want to make sure that I understand the order and what is happening in the function. Additionally, [x], is introducing a list?

Comment: @Yami2018 - yes, the first argument in the anonymous function, `x`, is the variable name and the second argument, `y`,  is the data frame name. Also, the output from `lapply()` is a `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply(house, table)`

If you want the frequency of each unique value in each column, this will work.